# .NET Automation ControlType.Document: how to manipulate text?

Tags: c#, .net, automation, document

How can I set text into a `ControlType.Document` element using the `System.Windows.Automation`?

The ValuePattern is not available for Document ControlType and TextPattern doesn't allow setting of new values.

This does not work:

```
automationElement.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern)
    .setValue(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an ugly way with this method:

```
private void InsertTextIntoAutomationElement(AutomationElement element, string value) {

    object valuePattern = null;

    if (!element.TryGetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern, out valuePattern)) {
        element.SetFocus();
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        SendKeys.SendWait("^{HOME}");   // Move to start of control
        SendKeys.SendWait("^+{END}");   // Select everything
        SendKeys.SendWait("{DEL}");     // Delete selection
        SendKeys.SendWait(value);
    } else{
        element.SetFocus();
        ((ValuePattern)valuePattern).SetValue(value);
    }
}
```